# Commonmark for Java - I want to render without paragraphs?

Tags: java, html, markdown, commonmark

I'm using the Atlassian Commonmark API found [here](https://github.com/atlassian/commonmark-java) to parse Markdown to HTML.
Works beautifully, but tends to add `<p`and `</p>`to the beginning and end of every parsed String.

Has anyone used the API extensively in the past and/or has any idea how I could get it to stop doing this?
Other than manually removing the paragraph afterwards, that is, which feels ... unclean somehow.

Edit for clarification: The converted code snippets are intended for use in an HTML table, so I don't need the paragraph bits before and after them.

The Markdown input might be:

```
####Text for the table here.
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
<p><h6>Text for the table here.</h6></p>
```

What I want is simply for the paragraph snips not to be added:

```
<h6>Text for the table here.</h6>
```

Comment: Based on your explanation, it sounds like it is working correctly. Could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41876676/edit) your question and provide a simple example input, the resulting output and your expected output?

Comment: @Waylan Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this as well. I achieved it by creating a simple custom renderer that does not render the top level `<p>`aragraphs.

It checks if the parent of a paragraph is the `Document` node and if yes it does only render the children of the paragraph.

It extends the default renderer (`CoreHtmlNodeRenderer`) to get access to `visitChildren()` and `visit(Paragraph)`

in kotlin:

```kotlin
class SkipParentWrapperParagraphsRenderer(val context: HtmlNodeRendererContext)
    : CoreHtmlNodeRenderer(context), NodeRenderer {

    override fun getNodeTypes(): Set<Class<out Node>> {
        return setOf(Paragraph::class.java)
    }
    
    override fun render(node: Node) {
        if (node.parent is Document) {
            visitChildren(node)
        } else {
            visit(node as Paragraph)
        }
    }
}
```

register the new renderer:

```kotlin
val renderer: HtmlRenderer = HtmlRenderer
    .builder()
    .nodeRendererFactory { context -> SkipParentWrapperParagraphsRenderer(context) }
    .build()
```

There is an [example in the documentation](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-java#customize-html-rendering).